# MX records without A records

Tags: domain-name-system, email, mx-record

I have a site hosted on [Openshift](http://openshift.redhat.com/) and it allows users to add domain name aliases using an external DNS provider. I'm using Cloudflare for my DNS. However, since Openshift's IP addresses are known to change, you have to use `CNAME` records instead of `A` records. (Bad, I know!)

However, this then breaks my `MX records` and I want to use my domain host's free email redirection service.

Is there any workaround for this problem?

Comment: Don't use their email service? Go third-party, Google Apps maybe?

Comment: But I'd still have to use their MX records right? So same problem still?

Comment: No, you can just set them to Google's MXes then.

Comment: I'm not sure I see the difference without an A record. If you can explain further how Google Apps works in an answer I'd be happy to vote for it.

Answer (score 4):

From RFC 2181:

10.3. MX and NS records

The domain name used as the value of a NS resource record, or part of
   the value of a MX resource record must not be an alias.  Not only is
   the specification clear on this point, but using an alias in either
   of these positions neither works as well as might be hoped, nor well
   fulfills the ambition that may have led to this approach.  **This
   domain name must have as its value one or more address records.**
   Currently **those will be A records**, however in the future other record
   types giving addressing information may be acceptable.  It can also
   have other RRs, **but never a CNAME RR**.

The reason for this is that you will need to do additional queries:

- ask the IP for the MX record -> CNAME
- ask the IP for this CNAME -> A record
- ask the IP for that A record -> finally the IP

This causes a lot of overhead

Comment: I'm totally aware of this and so is Openshift I believe but it's just the way it's done for now.

Comment: btw I'd go with Bar de Vos his solution and use google apps

Answer (score 0):

I'd simply use a smarthost.

Besides, OpenShift is being developed very rapidly, if you have an issue, post it in the community, and it will be addressed

Answer (score 0):

You can have an `MX` record without an `A` record, like below:

> yourdomain. IN MX 50 mail.otherserver.com.

Comment: But not with a CNAME, which he needs in order to use OpenShift

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround, like the guys in heroku state implicitly when talking about [avoiding naked domains](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/avoiding-naked-domains-dns-arecords). I have tried in OpenShift and it works the same.

1) If you own the domain `example.com`, create a subdomain `www.example.com`

2) Use `CNAME` records to alias `wwww.example.com` to `example-yournamespace-rhcloud.com`

3) Redirect permanently (301) `example.com` to `www.example.com`. For example, with `.htaccess`:

```
redirect 301 / http://www.example.com
```

4) You haven't touch `CNAME` neither `A` records, so you can configure freely your `MX` records.